# clientId is null while using swagger (both Swashbuckle & Swashbuckle.Core versions are 5.3.2) with Web Api (v5.2.3)

Tags: api, oauth, swagger

I am trying to setup swagger documentation for my Web API that uses OAuth (using OWIN middleware 'UseOAuthAuthorizationServer') but running into issues.

I have done OAuth swagger configuration as below:

General OAuth configuration with scopes:

```
                   c.OAuth2("oauth2")
                    .Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
                    .Flow("implicit")
                    .AuthorizationUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.AuthorizationHostUrl])
                    .TokenUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.TokenUrl])
                    .Scopes(scopes =>
                    {
                        scopes.Add("Admin", "Admin permission required");
                    });
```

Enabling OAuth for selected APIs:

```
         c.OperationFilter<AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements>();
```

Swagger UI configuration:

```
         c.EnableOAuth2Support("MyPortal", "test-realm", "Swagger UI");
```

With the above code, I can view toggle buttons on appropriate end point methods. When I click the button, it displays scopes according to above configuration as well.

Once, I select scope and hit authorization button, my OAuth server fails to authenticate because it first validates the client and it seems swagger is not passing client-id value. Issue is detected in my OAuth server i.e.,

```
  OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider::ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
```

method fails at below lines:

```
       if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out suppliedClientId, out suppliedClientSecret))
        {
            //if resource provider taking client credentials with FORMS authentication
            context.TryGetFormCredentials(out suppliedClientId, out suppliedClientSecret);
        }

        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "client_Id is not set");
            return;
        }
```

OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext argument has no information about the client.

While debugging, in the above method, I have escaped those failure points and successfully validated the client.

But still, I got below error for which I have no clue:

```
        unsupported_grant_type
```

Can someone help me how to fix these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you pass the client Id in. The following works for me:

Try:

```
c.EnableOAuth2Support("your Client Id here", "test-realm", "Swagger UI");
```

instead of

```
c.EnableOAuth2Support("MyPortal", "test-realm", "Swagger UI");
```

The AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements operation filter should look like this - you need to put your client id in where I've indicated:

```
public class AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements : IOperationFilter
    {
      public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
      {
        var actFilters = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline();
        var allowsAnonymous = actFilters.Select(f => f.Instance).OfType<OverrideAuthorizationAttribute>().Any();
        if (allowsAnonymous)
          return; 

        if (operation.security == null)
          operation.security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();

        var oAuthRequirements = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            {"oauth2", new List<string> {"your client id here"}}
        };

        operation.security.Add(oAuthRequirements);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I followed this article [link](http://www.wmpratt.com/part-ii-swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-enabling-oauth2/) and as per that article, I have set scopes to my role names. After your reply, I have hard coded the Dictionary value to my client -id (just for testing purpose) but still I am getting client-id as null.